# Atomically fetch and increase sequence value in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sequence

I convert the DB from Oracle to MySQL.
I'm using both Java & Hibernate.
When I used oracle I had the following method that gave me a brand new and unused sequence value:

```
protected int getSequenceNextValue() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL from DUAL");
    return ((BigDecimal) query.uniqueResult()).intValueExact();
}
```

And I'm trying to refactor this method to work on MySQL DB.
I have a table in MySQL that I use as a sequence (through Hibernate):

```
create table MY_SEQUENCE(
    next_val int(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Is there any thread safe way to get a new value from this table and in the same transction to increase it?

For most cases I use the Hibernate Generator to generate a new sequence using this table, but in several cases I need to do it manually.

The best solution for me will be a refactoring of the method above, in such way that threads that querying the table at the same time will not fail, but will wait for each other.

Thanks...

Comment: start transaction; call getSeqNextValue(); commit;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the InnoDB table type and FOR UPDATE. An example similar to what you describe is in the MySQL manual here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: I will read about this table type, to see its cons/pros over the 'normal' mySQL table.
Can you give me some highlights?

Comment: The default storage engine is MyISAM, offering fast performance but no transaction safety. InnoDB provides transaction safety, allowing you to perform the single logical operation described atomically. It also provides other ACID-comliant features.The 'start transaction', 'commit' syntax will have no effect on the MyISAM table type.

Comment: From what I read, the LAST_INSERT_ID() method doesn't work when called from multiple DB sessions, so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: I was referring to this example from that page. It's a post-increment.

`SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;`